# Which type of project permission is better in Project server 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

I have MS Project server 2013 integrated with SharePoint 2013

Project server has two type of permission modes

1. SharePoint permission mode
2. Project server permission mode

I have read [blogs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161361.aspx), but I am confused which permission is better to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Project Server Permission Mode**

[This permissions mode](https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140818132857-173652244-how-does-project-server-permissions-work?trk=prof-post) is a flexible mechanism that enables to set permissions of users to Project Server objects by managing users, groups and categories.

Project Sever administrator may fully customize the groups and categories setting, and also may create additional groups and categories.

This permissions mode is used on previous Project Server versions.

**SharePoint Permission Mode**

On SharePoint Permission Mode, things are simplified. It is suitable for organizations that find Project Server permissions mechanism hard to implement, or for those who are well acquainted with SharePoint permissions administration.

This mode uses 7 predefined permissions groups with associated categories:

- Administrator
- Portfolio Managers
- Portfolio Viewers
- Project Managers
- Resource Managers
- Team Leads
- Team Members

Global permissions are managed by association of users to predefined SharePoint permission groups.

Permissions to projects sites and resources is granted by associating the user to one of the 3 predefined groups, which are created automatically per project site (a specific project):

- Visitors - reflects read only privileges
- Members - reflects Team Member privileges
- Owners - reflects Project Manager privileges

For example, a user is associated to the global Team Member permissions group, and on a specific project he is associated to Owner permissions group. This means that on that specific project he has r/w permissions, the same as the project manager, but on other projects he is only a team member.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140827115234-173652244-sharepoint-vs-project-permissions

Answer (score 1):

**This depends on your business requirements**,

- Project Server permission mode is flexible but complex.
- SharePoint permission mode is simple but does not match the most business requirement

**SharePoint permissions Mode consideration/tips,**

- You cannot edit the default permissions assigned to any of these SharePoint groups.
- You cannot create additional custom groups, categories, Resource Breakdown Structure (RBS) nodes, or edit the default permissions assigned to any of these objects.
- Delegates cannot be used.

**Project Server permissions consideration/tips,**

- Do not associate a user to a category.
- Do not define Global Permissions to a user.
- Do not set Global Permissions to a user.
- Avoid the use of Deny.

**The important note that you should be aware of is**

> If the SharePoint Mode has been activated and you intend to switch to
> Project Server Mode, you should keep in mind that all SharePoint Mode
> Configuration settings will be removed and vice versa. For more details, you can check [**SharePoint Permission Mode Vs Project Server Permission Mode in Project Server 2013**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/project-server-permission-mode/)